# How can the base directory be replaced with gulp?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I need to alter a stream of files to contain a different base folder name.  I thought the gulp-rename plugin would allow for this, but it only seems to replace the glob portion.

Example:

```
gulp.task("test", function() {
  gulp.src("bower_components/**/*", { base: "bower_components", read:false })
    .pipe($.rename(function (p) { p.dirname = "X/" + p.dirname; }))
    .pipe($.print());
});
```

outputs:

```
[gulp] bower_components\X\jquery\test\data\offset\scroll.html
[gulp] bower_components\X\jquery\test\data\offset\static.html
[gulp] bower_components\X\jquery\test\data\offset\table.html
...
```

I want

```
[gulp] X\jquery\test\data\offset\scroll.html
[gulp] X\jquery\test\data\offset\static.html
[gulp] X\jquery\test\data\offset\table.html
...
```

Is there a way to do this with gulp-replace, or some other plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this with `gulp-tap` to get a hold of the the file instances and alter properties on them before they get printed or use it to print them.

Out of curiosity what are you aiming to do?

Hope that helps!

EDIT-1::

The following is a slightly modified version of the example in the `gulp-tap` documentation which may work for your use case.

```
gulp.src("src/**/*.{coffee,js}")
  .pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
    file.path = 'X/' + file.path;
  }))
  .pipe($.print())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

EDIT-2::

This is a common task I have set up in my projects for handling external scripts (note; I am using `gulp-load-plugins` hence invoking my plugins with `plugins.<NAME>`);

```
gulp.task('vendor:scripts:publish', function() {
  return gulp.src(sources.vendor.js)
    .pipe(plugins.plumber())
    .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(plugins.rename(pluginOpts.rename))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
});
```

`destinations` and `sources` are two variables that I have defined in a config file for my gulpfile.

But for clarity, `sources.vendor.js` points at an array much like the following;

```
js: [
  'src/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
  'src/vendor/lodash/lodash.js',
  'src/vendor/backbone/backbone.js'
],
```

The reason my folder is named `vendor` and not `bower_components` is because I've made use of a `.bowerrc` file to point my bower installation at a different folder.

In addition if you have discrete scripts that you may not want to include all of the time you can look to make use of `gulp-utils` and `gulp-filter` to filter out certain scripts when an option is passed or not passed when `gulp` is invoked on the CLI.

For example; having `gulp vendor:scripts:publish` include all scripts but `gulp vendor:scripts:publish --release` omitting discrete scripts.

This then requires modifying your task to declare a filter that is piped in based on an option flag being picked up by `gulp-utils`.

```
var isRelease = (plugins.utils.env.release) ? true: false;

gulp.task('vendor:scripts:publish', function() {
  var discreteFilter = plugins.filter([
    '**/*.js',
    '!**/discrete.min.js'
  ]);
  return gulp.src(sources.vendor.js)
    .pipe(plugins.plumber())
    .pipe(isRelease ? discreteFilter: plugins.utils.noop())
    .pipe(plugins.concat('vendor.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(plugins.rename(pluginOpts.rename))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destinations.js));
  });
```

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: Can you provide an example?  It isn't clear from the plugin page how you would do what I need it to do.

Comment: This will be off of what I can remember without loading something up but I believe if you pipe in `gulp-tap`, each file will have properties such as `path`, `name` and `content`.

When you get an instance of the file like in the example on the `gulp-tap` docs, you can update `file.path` with the desired value and see what `print` then gives you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is it you're trying to do by outputting a different file path?

Comment: I have a destination folder where I've copied bower components along with a couple of other 3rd-party components that aren't able to be retrieved through bower.  I then need to inject all of those into my html.  Using main-bower-files gives me the bower files in the right dependency order, but then I need to inject all the other ones, so I was planning on converting something like "src/**/*.js" to "dest/**/*.js" so I can get a list of my non-bower dependnecies, but inject as if it had the prefix of "dest/**/*.js".  Maybe there's a better way to achieve the same end.

Comment: So to clarify, your aim is to take some bower components and some other 3rd party components that aren't available through bower and inject them scripts into your html markup? May I suggest creating an array of the files that you need and concatenating them into one file aptly named something like `vendor.js`. Then you only require the one line in your markup -- I will update the answer to include my normal approach to this.

Comment: The gulp-tap plugin does let you manipulate the path, but once you tack something on the front it turns the path into an absolute path that I have to mess with (which I've been doing unsuccessfully for 5 minutes or so).  Concerning your suggestions, I'm actually already using concat, uglify, etc. for my release builds, but want to inject discrete scripts for my debug builds.

Comment: For discrete scripts you could use a filter in combo with a `gulp-utils` variable to determine when certain scripts should be included. Then for example, by default `gulp` includes all but `gulp --release` would omit the discrete scripts.

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow exactly what you're describing, but regardless I'm not really looking to completely rework my build.  Right now, I'm just looking for a way to get a stream of file names and change the prefix.  The gulp-tap comes close, but isn't producing the exact results I want.  if you run your edit 1 example, I think you'll find that it produces absolute paths with your prefix (at least on Windows).

Comment: I don't think `gulp-tap` is the right plugin for what you're trying to do. If I understand rightly you are essentially trying to include your external scripts within your markup and upon release omits certain scripts. The clean way to do this is a combination of `gulp-filter` and `gulp-utils` along with `gulp-concat` etc. It doesn't require a rework of your build, just requires a more appropriate task for the job. If you're set on the approach of manipulating file paths etc. there are probably better plugins available through the node ecosystem that could be used but IMO unnecessary.

Comment: I don't know that you're following what I'm trying to do exactly, as I'm always including the exact same scripts.  I'm just doing concat/minify/etc. for my release builds.  That doesn't really matter though as I could just as well be always injecting discrete scripts all the time.  Ultimately, I'm just looking for something like the gulp-rename plugin that actually allows me to rename the entire path.